# SMTP Issue: did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MTA

Tags: email, sendmail, smtp, liferay

We need to create a mail server to send mail for our Portal application using Liferay. The mail account will be an administrative account to maintain the portal.

I was able to send mail successfully using sendmail. But when sending mail through Liferay, mails are not sent and could see the following error in the mail log file with `grep ': r5R5jcf9031963: ' /var/log/maillog`:

```
Jun 27 11:15:38 testser sendmail[31963]: r5R5jcf9031963: [192.168.12.12]  did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MTA
```

Some system information:

```
$ rpm -q sendmail
sendmail-8.13.8-8.el5
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.5 (Final)
```

For configuring mail in Liferay, I entered the following information: SMTP Server, SMTP port, username and password.

But if I keep "Username and Password" blank in the Liferay portal settings, mails are sent successfully. In that case mails are sent from the default `test` Liferay user. But I want the mail to be sent from the user which I configured using sendmail rather than from the default Liferay user.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have authentication set up in sendmail. The application is probably sending an `AUTH` command which sendmail is not expecting. I'm not familiar with sendmail, but that might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Please grep the mail log for either message ID and edit the full output into the question. For example, `grep ': r5R5jcf9031963: ' /var/log/maillog` (note that when editing, you can use the `{}` button to format as code, which will be useful). Also please add which version of Sendmail you are running (and your OS and distribution, particularly if you are not building Sendmail from source).

Comment: The log message looks like sombebody did `telnet testser 25` just to check that the server was up, and issued a `quit` instead of initiating a transaction. If that is the case, the title of your question is a red herring, and the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: What does this mean: "But I want the mail to be sent from the user which I configured using sendmail rather than from the default Liferay user."

Comment: While configuring Mail Settings in Liferay,if I just add SMTP Server Address/Port without adding UserName and Password, the mail works fine but the mail is sent from default liferay application user'test@liferay.com' .What I want that along WITH SMTP server settings in Liferay,If i add username and password in Liferay Mail Settings,mail should go from that user rather than from default liferay user.I want this to be working. My sendmail configuration is not supporting AUTH command which might be the issue. #telnet 192.168.12.12 25
AUTH PLAIN
504 5.3.3 AUTH mechanism PLAIN not available